# backbone passing parameters to a model url

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette

In my controller I'm passing in a parameter called 'url' to a view. This is passed successfully into the initialize function. Next when I create my model I would like to pass the same parameter into the model to use as the rooturl.

Below is what I have tried but I got the following error message:

```
A "url" property or function must be specified
```

This seems like the parameter is not being passed to the model (undefined) or I'm not calling it correctly in the model. **What I'm I doing wrong here?**

**Note:** console.log(options.url) in the initialize function view confirms the parameter is passed successfully from the controller to the view, the issues is from the view to the model where it is undefined.

**Controller:**

```
var myview = new NewView({
           url:"api/"
       })**
```

**View:**

```
  var myview = Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({

        initialize: function (options) {
            this.url = options.url;
            this.model.fetch();
        },


    model: new myModel({
            url: this.url
        }),
```

**myModel:**

```
var myModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
  urlRoot: function(){ return this.get('url') }

});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are trying to fetch your model with an empty url.

When you call:

```
initialize: function (options) {
  this.url = options.url;
  this.model.fetch();
}
```

`fetch` here, you don't have the url for the model. So, you could do:

```
initialize: function (options) {
  this.url = options.url;
  this.model.set({url: this.url});
  this.model.fetch();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When writing

```
model: new myModel({
        url: this.url
    }),
```

the view is not yet initialized

You can instantiate the model in the view's initialize method

```
initialize: function (options) {
        this.url = options.url;
        this.model = new myModel({
            url: this.url
        })
        this.model.fetch();
    },
```

Comment: It does not seem to like that giving Cannot call method 'fetch' of undefined message. url is still undefined in the model.